# How to restore backbonejs full route after a browser refresh

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is an architectural question about *Backbone JS*:

`AppView` that contains a *DOM* element placeholder that is loaded with `LeadsView`.
`LeadsView` contains a *DOM* placeholder to present `LeadView`

My current route is `#app/leads/1` which means that all 3 *Views* are loaded.
 `AppView`->`LeadsView`-> `LeadView` of lead *#1*.

Now suddenly the user hit the refresh button of the browser. The router would try to take it to `#app/leads/:1` which routes to `"app/leads/:lead_id" : "showLeadView"`, but `AppView` and `LeadsView` has not been rendered this time, hence the rendering of `LeadView` will fail.

It's looking for the *DOM* element to render itself into, but cannot find it.

How is that handled with *Backbone*?

TIA,
Nimrod.

Comment: How did you render all these views initially? Obviously not within a route handler - that's what you have to do. Your router should inspect th current route and decide how to render the views accordingly.

Comment: Oh. Further: "`AppView that contains a DOM element placeholder that is loaded with LeadsView. LeadsView contains a DOM placeholder to present LeadView`" reads as you're specifing the target elements directly like `view.render(); view.$el.appendTo($("#directly-addressed-element"))`. Consider nesting the views, you would then `subView.render(); subView.$el.appendTo(this.$el); // where this.$el is the current view`. _You should provide more code of your views and router that outlines the structure._

Comment: thank you @try-catch-finally you got it right, I didn't render the subviews as such, rather accessing the elements directly.
Good catch :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically initialize and `render` the other views when the  `"app/leads/:lead_id" : "showLeadView"` route is hit.

The problem now becomes: *How to find if a view was rendered or not ?*

I solved this by adding a new property to my *Models* and *Collections* that would tell me if they were populated (either if they were fetched or if they have attributes set). An implementation for this can be found in the [*Thorax* library repo](https://github.com/walmartlabs/thorax/blob/master/src/model.js).

And it looks like this:

```
isPopulated: function() {
  /*jshint -W089 */

  // We are populated if we have attributes set
  var attributes = _.clone(this.attributes),
      defaults = getValue(this, 'defaults') || {};
  for (var default_key in defaults) {
    if (attributes[default_key] != defaults[default_key]) {
      return true;
    }
    delete attributes[default_key];
  }
  var keys = _.keys(attributes);
  return keys.length > 1 || (keys.length === 1 && keys[0] !== this.idAttribute);
}
```

With this method i can verify if the collection needed to render the parent views has been populated. If it was't than call the methods that would be called if you navigated to `app` and then to `leads` (you practically access the routes programmatically).

It could look something like this:

```
if(!appModel.isPopulated())
    this.showAppView();

if(!leadsCollection.isPopulated())
    this.showLeadsView();
```

As you can see this means keeping references to `appModel` and `leadsCollection` in your router.

#### Update (clarification)

In the first line of my answer I was mentioning something like this:

- `AppView` has a reference to a sub-view `LeadsView` that has a reference to a sub-view `LeadView`.
- in your router you have an instance of `AppView`.
- you pass `appModel` to `AppView` and call `.render()` on it when you hit `app` router.
- you pass `leadsCollection` to `AppView.getLeadsView()` and call `.render()` on it when you hit `leads` route.
- you pass the right `lead` model from `leadsCollection` to `AppView.getLeadsView().getLeadView()` and call `.render()` on it when you hit the route.

**Or you can use something like Thorax**

It already adds handling for subviews (takes care of event delegation, event destruction, DOM cleaning, etc.) and offers template handlers for it so you can point in your template where you want the sub-view to be rendered.

I hope now, it is clearer what I meant and as you can see it answers your question.

Comment: I understand, but really I thought this couldn't be the right architectural design, and in fact as @try-catch-finally mentioned, the right way to do it is by using sub views rather than accessing dom elements directly on those views. I do agree however that rendering and already rendered document fragment may be redundant, and for that we have to check if it's not already rendered.

Comment: In the first line of my answer I was mentioning exactly what @try-catch-finally said. By **You can programmatically initialize and render the other views** (this means the other views are subviews and you call the `.render()` method on them. And as I said in my answer you real problem becomes finding whether they were rendered or not already.

Comment: Why didn't you think that using sub-views that are rendered when the route is hit, is bad architecture ?

Comment: Updated my answer with clarification. Btw, your question was *how to do it*, not *what is the best way*.